# Showing custom text on the taskbar browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

For example suppose you have 3 notifications in Facebook.

When you open the website, you see a browser tab (?) on the taskbar showing '(3) Your name' in Chrome or '(3)Facebook- Mozilla...' in Firefox.

For a webpage, the title value (plus  browser dependent text) is shown as text in the browser tab and on the taskbar.

How can I add the number of notifications (i.e. 3 here) there? Is it done with HTML, JavaScript or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of the title could either be set by the default HTML originating from the server-side in the `<title></title>` element, or it could be set using the [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title) property in Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Well you answered most of this question yourself.

The missing piece of the puzzle is that you can change the page title dynamically using javascript:

```
document.title = "(2) New title"
```